# Android Studio ItemOnClickListener with ItemFilter and XML Problem

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a question reagrding to RecyclerViews in Android Studio. I want to be able to start a newActivity on item Click and pass with somthing to be able to identify it in my Constants folder to get all the Informations about the Item. Position is not enought beacause I have implemented an Item Filter that changes positions of the itmes from filter to filter. Code is a bit messy im a newby and code isn't cleand up.

Fragment with RecyclerView:

This is the part that redirects:

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                val intent = Intent(context, ExerciseActivity::class.java)
                Constants.PositionItemListener = position
                intent.putExtra("Position", Constants.PositionItemListener)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
```

This is the whole code of fragment:

```
package ch.skimfit.skimfitapp

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.RadioButton
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import ch.skimfit.skimfitapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

private lateinit var adapter : RecyclerViewAdapterTraining
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var exerciseList:ArrayList<Exercises>
private lateinit var tempArrayList:ArrayList<Exercises>

lateinit var exerciseImage:Array<Int>
lateinit var exerciseName:Array<String>

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [home.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class home : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null


    private lateinit var content:ArrayList<Exercises>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

    }


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment home.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            home().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dataInitialize()
        setupFilter()
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_All)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        var adapter = RecyclerViewAdapterTraining(tempArrayList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : RecyclerViewAdapterTraining.onItemClickListerner{
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                val intent = Intent(context, ExerciseActivity::class.java)
                Constants.PositionItemListener = position
                intent.putExtra("Position", Constants.PositionItemListener)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupFilter() {
        var rbAll: RadioButton? = view?.findViewById(R.id.rbAll)
        var rbPush:RadioButton? = view?.findViewById(R.id.rbPush)
        var rbPull:RadioButton? = view?.findViewById(R.id.rbPull)
        var rbLeg:RadioButton? = view?.findViewById(R.id.rbLeg)

        rbAll?.setOnClickListener{
            tempArrayList.clear()
            exerciseList.forEach {
                if(it.Category.contains("exercise")){
                    tempArrayList.add(it)
                }
            }
            recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
        rbPush?.setOnClickListener{
            tempArrayList.clear()
            exerciseList.forEach {
                if(it.Category.contains("push")){
                    tempArrayList.add(it)
                }
            }
            recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        rbPull?.setOnClickListener{
            tempArrayList.clear()
            exerciseList.forEach {
                if(it.Category.contains("pull")){
                    tempArrayList.add(it)
                }
            }
            recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        rbLeg?.setOnClickListener{
            tempArrayList.clear()
            exerciseList.forEach {
                if(it.Category.contains("leg")){
                    tempArrayList.add(it)
                }
            }
            recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun dataInitialize(){
        exerciseList = Constants.getExerciseList()
        tempArrayList = Constants.getExerciseList()

    }
}
```

Constants:

```
package ch.skimfit.skimfitapp

object Constants {

    var PositionItemListener: Int = 0

    fun getExerciseList(): ArrayList<Exercises> {
        val exerciseList = ArrayList<Exercises>()

        val exe1 = Exercises(1,"Push exercise 1", R.drawable.training_recyclerview, "Test", "Test1", 0, 0, "pushexercise")
        exerciseList.add(exe1)
        val exe2 = Exercises(2,"Pull exercise 1", R.drawable.training_recyclerview, "Test", "Test2", 0, 0,"pullexercise")
        exerciseList.add(exe2)
        val exe3 = Exercises(3,"Pull exercise 2", R.drawable.training_recyclerview, "Test", "Test3", 0, 0, "pullexercise")
        exerciseList.add(exe3)
        val exe4 = Exercises(4,"Pull exercise 3", R.drawable.training_recyclerview, "Test", "Test4", 0, 0, "pullexercise")
        exerciseList.add(exe4)
        val exe5 = Exercises(5,"leg exercise 1", R.drawable.training_recyclerview, "Test", "Test5", 0, 0, "legexercise")
        exerciseList.add(exe5)
        val exe6 = Exercises(6,"leg exercise 2", R.drawable.training_recyclerview, "Test", "Test6", 0, 0, "legexercise")
        exerciseList.add(exe6)

        return exerciseList
    }
}
```

And another Question:

Why is my Frame Layout in xml not Connecting to the complete Top if i constrain it to parent top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundMain"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/BottomNavBarColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_bar_color_selected"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_bar_color_selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want it to be like the red line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Cpt.png)

Comment: your `Exercises` instances contains item information. you can change `intent.putExtra("Position", Constants.PositionItemListener)` to `intent.putExtra("Position", tempArrayList.get(position).position)`

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution that works for me. Probably not the best one but working. Im now just passing in which Category the user is currently in to setup the same tempList in my receiving Activity. But still no solution for xml Problem.
Edit: Okay found the problem in xml just had a padding of ActionBarSize in the top.